# acumatica generic inquiry MAX , MIN

Tags: acumatica

When writing a generic inquiry is there any way to include a clause for max, min filter.  For example how do you write a generic inquiry to get last purchase order for suppliers. or last purchase price for items which is a typical example.

Supplier A   PO005
Supplier B   PO007

Thanks

Comment: As I know there is no such ability in the generic inquires right now. Right now the default aggregate will be applied to all fields if you are using group by. However, you can implement desired behavior with customization project.

Answer (score 3):

There is a hidden column with Aggregate function on the GI Designer.
[image]
You can use for define function for each separate field. 
Default function is Max()